# How to click a Button in Javascript with Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

Hey I'm trying to figure out how to click this simple little button but I'm  failing.

This is the correct code implementation but wrong path in javascript. I need to click on the a<

Or if I can just call the function connected to the button

[image]

[image]

I've also tried to click on the td< but nothings happens because the button is actually the a<

Code:

```
 // no errors print but nothing happens
self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('participant-page-results-more').click();"){ (value, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }

    }
```

**UPDATED Answer still nothing but I think were close, @Michael Hulet:**

```
       self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('#participant-page-results-more').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();"){ (value, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
        }
    } 

    // Or

        self.MainWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('#participant-page-results-more a').click();"){ (value, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
        }
    }
```

But interestingly enough when I use the .innerText in stead of the .click a get back the Show more matches label.

**UPDATE 2:**

trying to load the function directly does nothing either

```
  self.MainWebView.evaluateJavaScript("window.loadMoreGames();"){ (value, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
    }

    // Or

    self.MainWebView.evaluateJavaScript("window[loadMoreGames]"){ (value, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
    }

    // Or

    self.MainWebView.evaluateJavaScript("loadMoreGames();"){ (value, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to trigger the function, you need to click on the `<a>` tag (the HTML tag that listens for clicks), but the `id` you're looking up is on the `<table>` tag. Note that the key change here is a different selector/selection method, but try this:

```
self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('#participant-page-results-more a').click();"){ (value, error) in

    if let err = error {
        print(err)
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you just call `loadMoreGames()` directly instead of going through the whole song and dance of getting the `<a>` tag?

Comment: I can tell you. If I know how to write out the code for it. Think you can help me out?

Comment: Instead of passing all that you're doing rn to `evaluateJavaScript`, try just passing `loadMoreGames();` (or `window.loadMoreGames();` if you get anything about `loadMoreGames` being `undefined`)

Comment: And it works just fine if you manually click on the button yourself on your device?

Comment: yea that's the bad part everything seems perfect