# Click a Button in HTML with Swift

Tags: javascript, html, swift

I have a button in my Swift project,

Can I click the HTML button with the Swift button?

This is my Swift button:

```
@IBAction func buttonclick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //click html button when click swift button
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<a id="htmlbutton" class="buton" onClick="clickbutton('data')" >Click</a>
```

I use wkWebView in my project and this html code from my website

Sorry for my bad English.

please check the image

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to NSAttributedString in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217820/convert-html-to-nsattributedstring-in-ios)

Comment: Hi @Do2 I have found the similar question but there is no solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523277/how-to-click-a-button-in-javascript-with-swift

Comment: Did you read the answers on my link?

Comment: Yes, I did. I just want to click button in my website from swift button.

Comment: How would you do that? I don't understand. Give me an example...

Comment: I have added an image to my question. please check it.

Comment: Check this article, i think it will help you https://mislavjavor.github.io/2016-03-08/WKWebView-advanced-tutorial/ good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually trigger a click on the HTML button by injecting and running a JS script using `WKWebView`'s `evaluateJavaScript` method. The script might look like this: `document.getElementById('htmlbutton').click();`.