# Using EvaluateJavaScript to click a button unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a UIViewController that has a WKWebView that loads a particular view with a button that needs to be clicked automatically. To tackle this, I used the WKNavigationDelegate protocol function `didFinish` and an utilizing WKWebView's `evaluateJavaScript` method. Here is my implementation

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('myButtonClass')[0].click()") { (result, error) in
            print("ERROR: \(error)")
            print("RESULT: \(result)")
        }
    }
```

So once the page is loaded, I am attempting to click a certain button on the screen (keep in mind, there is only one button with this class name on this particular page view). When this code runs, both `result` and `error` get printed out, and both of them are `nil`. Yet, the button is not clicked and WKWebView never redirects to the link the button links to.

How is it possible that there is no `error` but nothing happens?

Am I missing some sort of navigation set up or something?

Comment: have you figured this out ?

Comment: I got it to work using the accepted answer in this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523277/how-to-click-a-button-in-javascript-with-swift

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing **;** inside the script. Try this

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('myButtonClass')[0].click();") { (result, error) in
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
        print("RESULT: \(result)")
    }
}
```